# Getting build error :error C2011: 'ProfileSettings' : 'class' type redefinition

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, header, activex

When I am adding header file from existing project to new ActiveX Control dll project, getting below error :

error C2011: 'ProfileSettings' : 'class' type redefinition.

Strange thing is that, same header file included into another projects as well, for which during build not getting such errors.

I looked as possible solutions from google, many answers are include header guard, but same file included into old projects as well, in which not getting such error. Can you please help me? Is there any project configuration which I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In new project, there was reference of one existing project. Referenced project also included file with "ProfileSettings" Class.

After setting below Property to false, able to build successfully :

Common Properties --> References --> (click on referenced project) --> Reference Assembly Output --> Set to FALSE